# I want to dump the contents of a .csv file into a string in Visual Basic 6. What's wrong with my code?

Tags: file, vb6, csv

Here is my code.  The file abc.csv exists and is full of data.

```
    Dim strContent As String
    Dim int As Integer      

    Open "C:\abc.csv" For Input As #int 

        strContent = Input(LOF(int), int)

    Close #int
```

The error that I get is that the code proceeds as if the file never existed...but it does exist in the C:\ drive directory.  I made extra sure of it.  C:\abc.csv is there....What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
int = FreeFile
Open "C:\abc.csv" For Input As #int
```

Comment: That was it!  I didn't assign int to FreeFile.  THANKS for catching that James.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a VB6 environment to test this in, but I think you want to try it like this:

```
Dim strContent As String
Dim int As Integer      
int = FreeFile
Open "C:\abc.csv" For Input As #int 
strContent = Input(LOF(int), #int) '<-- make sure to put the # on the 2nd param
Close #int
```

See here for more info (under Using the Open method in Classic VB):
http://www.vbknowledgebase.com/?Id=23&Desc=Read-Text-File-into-string-VB6